# Skew an image on the sides without distortion

Tags: jquery, css, transform, owl-carousel, skew

I want to skew the image using css in owl-carousel.

SCSS:

```
.owl-item {
    > div {
        transform: skew(-20deg, 0);
        overflow: hidden;

        > img {
            transform: skew(20deg, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="owl-carousel" id="promo">
    <div><img src="/images/slide1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="/images/slide2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="/images/slide3.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Can't make it work. At now it looks like that: https://yadi.sk/i/5Y8RQ5ts3N4iny

I want it to be looking: https://yadi.sk/i/PjzaXEx93N4iuV

but without the image distortion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image inside a container div. Apply the `skew` transform to the container div, lets say `transform: skew(20deg)`. Then the image is distorted, just like you say. But if you apply `skew(-20deg)` to the image inside the container, it looks all normal. Add some additional properties to the container and you can achieve the desired result.

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBPxjY

Comment: You mean to add image as background? Won't work with plain image?

Comment: I guess you could make it work... I don't know how owl carousel works tbh